# Determine charger type

Tags: android, usb

I'm creating an app that will tell users where they can find phone charging points and would like to know if there is a way to determine charger type (Micro USB or USB Type-C) in Android.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm sure that system doesn't know USB type. I think so because I'm sure USB does not have such information

Comment: @Amy - I have just searched on the internet if that is even possible.

Comment: How will you find phone charging points? You could have a local database with the list of all phones and their charger type. So when the app starts search through that database and compare it with the current phone's name.

Comment: @Tony - thanks for a great idea.